# Drop nan of each column in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I have a dataframe as example:

```
     A     B     C
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    1     2
4    1     2
5    1     2
6          2     3
7          2     3
8          2     3
9                3
10               3
11               3
```

And I would like to remove nan values of each column to get the result:

```
     A     B     C
0    1     2     3
1    1     2     3
2    1     2     3
3    1     2     3
4    1     2     3
5    1     2     3
```

Do I have an easy way to do that?

Comment: How do you decide which values to put on the same row? You're just moving values on each column without being interested in the connection with other values in the same row?

Comment: Are there actually nans or empty strings in your data? Please clarify. As posted, I can't see any nans.

Comment: Exactly, This results are obtained from crop simulation with 3 days of step. I do not need the connection with values in same row. I just need the connection between columns, where the first not nan value is the first day in crop season and follows

Comment: empty values are nan

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a custom sorting function for each column that doesn't actually sort numerically, it justs moves all the NaN values to the end of the column. Then, `dropna`:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: sorted(x, key=lambda v: isinstance(v, float) and np.isnan(v))).dropna()
```

Output:

```
>>> df
     A    B    C
0  1.0  2.0  3.0
1  1.0  2.0  3.0
2  1.0  2.0  3.0
3  1.0  2.0  3.0
4  1.0  2.0  3.0
5  1.0  2.0  3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Given

```
>>> df 
      A    B    C
0   1.0  NaN  NaN
1   1.0  NaN  NaN
2   1.0  NaN  NaN
3   1.0  2.0  NaN
4   1.0  2.0  NaN
5   1.0  2.0  NaN
6   NaN  2.0  3.0
7   NaN  2.0  3.0
8   NaN  2.0  3.0
9   NaN  NaN  3.0
10  NaN  NaN  3.0
11  NaN  NaN  3.0
```

use

```
>>> df.apply(lambda s: s.dropna().to_numpy()) 
     A    B    C
0  1.0  2.0  3.0
1  1.0  2.0  3.0
2  1.0  2.0  3.0
3  1.0  2.0  3.0
4  1.0  2.0  3.0
5  1.0  2.0  3.0
```

Comment: Nice! Shorter: `df.apply(lambda s: s.dropna().tolist())` (+1 soon)

Comment: @richardec cool! I did some timings and it seems to be fastest with `.to_numpy()`.

Comment: Ah! I didn't think about the possibility of there being a speed difference between `tolist` and `to_numpy`. That's really good to know.